# Nested class' property not visible in ListView after assignment

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, nested

I have a class with two nested classes. Properties of both nested classes should be shown in a WPF ListView. When the ListView is created the second nested class (BClass) is null. After pressing a button (e.g.) BClass gets a value.
My problem is that the ListView is not updated with this new value.

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my quick and dirty sample code (PropertyChangedBase from Caliburn Micro):

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class AClass : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public string prop2;
        public string Prop2
        {
            get { return prop2; }
            set
            {
                prop2 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Prop2");
            }
        }
    }

    public class BClass : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public string prop1;
        public string Prop1
        {
            get { return prop1; }
            set
            {
                prop1 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("Prop1");
            }
        }
    }

    public class CClass : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public AClass a;
        public AClass A
        {
            get { return a; }
            set
            {
                a = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("A");
            }
        }
        public BClass b;
        public BClass B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set
            {
                b = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("B");
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<CClass> cs = new List<CClass>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cs.Add(new CClass { A = new AClass { Prop2 = "WWW" } });
            listView.ItemsSource = cs;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cs.First().B = new BClass { Prop1 = "EEE" };
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="248" Margin="63,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="403">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A.Prop2}" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B.Prop1}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: try binding your ItemSource to an ObservableCollection<CClass> instead of a List.

Comment: None of these are "nested" classes, they are simple member properties of `CClass`.

Comment: Tried ObservableCollection already with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Bind listview to observable collection

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<CClass> cs = new ObservableCollection<CClass>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cs.Add(new CClass { A = new AClass { Prop2 = "WWW" } });
        listView.ItemsSource = cs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me!
It always worked. The column just didn't resize, so I couldn't see the result.